# why am I not able to download multiple files from FTP to local directories using perl?

Tags: perl, ftp

I have written the following code to connect to a ftp location and download a single file to my local filesystem.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Net::FTP;

my $hostname = 'mirror.anl.gov';
my $username = 'anonymous';
my $password = 'username@domain.com';

# Hardcode the directory and filename to get
my $home = '/pub';
my $filename = 'motd';

# Hardcode the local directory
my $localdir = '/home/boy/';

# Open the connection to the host

my $ftp = Net::FTP->new($hostname)
    or die "Cannot connect to $hostname: $@";     # Construct object

$ftp->login($username, $password)
    or die "Cannot login ", $ftp->message;;       # Log in

$ftp->cwd($home)
    or die "Cannot change working directory ", $ftp->message;# Change 
+directory

my @filelist=$ftp->ls($home);        

print map { "$_\n"} @filelist;

# Now get the file and leave
$ftp->get($filename,$localdir.$filename)
    or die "Cannot get $filename: $@"; 

$ftp->quit;
```

There is no issue at all, it is downloading and storing a single file on my LFS. But I have multiple files to download. So, I used `foreach` loop on `@filelist` as below

```
foreach(@filelist){    
print map { "$_\n"} @filelist;

    # Now get the file and leave
    $ftp->get($filename,$localdir.$filename)
        or die "Cannot get $filename: $@"; 
}
```

But now I am getting error on the last `die`. Since I had to get multiple files, so now I removed the `$filename` from my code, and now the `foreach` loop looks like below:

```
foreach(@filelist){    
print map { "$_\n"} @filelist;

# Now get the file and leave
$ftp->get($localdir)
    or die "Cannot get $filename: $@"; 
}
```

But again I got the same error. Now I came to know that `get` function is used when we need to download just single file and `mget` when we need to download multiple files. But when I used ̀mget`, I am getting below error:

```
can not locate object method 'mget' via package NET::FTP
```

So how do we got about accomplishing my task?

Comment: `print map { "$_\n"} @filelist` is a valid use of `map`, but is trying a bit too hard to be clever. `print "$_\n" for @filelist` is shorter and more readable.

Comment: It would be cleaner to `chdir $localdir` and then `$ftp->get($filename)`, avoiding the construction of absolute file paths. The loop would become a simple `chdir $localdir; $ftp->get($_) for $ftp->ls($home);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I came to know that `get` function is used when we need to download just single file and `mget` when we need to download multiple files

`mget` is a command available in some FTP clients (IBM, Microsoft, etc.) But does not exist in [**RFC 959**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959), the FTP specification. It is also not available from the `Net::FTP` module. It must be implemented using the `NLST` (name list) and `GET` commands, plus an internal inplementation of a `glob` filter if required.

Note the the RFC says about `NLST`

> This command is intended
> to return information that can be used by a program to
> further process the files automatically.  For example, in
> the implementation of a "multiple get" function.

Answer (score 3):

You loop over the filelist, but you don't make any use of the iterator (i.e. each element of the list).

```
for my $filename (@filelist) {
    $ftp->get($filename, "$localdir/$filename")
        or die "...";
}
```

Comment: if I use $filename in the for loop, then wouldn't I need some input in the variable before I use it in the loop? Initially I used $filename to hardcode my code with just single file name,but I removed it as I don't want to hard code the file name. Now with your suggested loop, what would be the value of $filename?

Comment: In each iteration of the loop, it will have the value of one of the elements of the array @filelist.

Comment: Thank you for your advice..It worked like a charm. Issue resolved